# android creating an excel file from template

Tags: android, excel

I'm wondering if there is a way to use an excel file (template ) to create other excel files using Java Excel API , I know it is possible with the API but how to add the template to android ? I don't want to use external storage , is there a way to add it as a resource ?
Thanks for your help .

Comment: How are you creating excel file from the template? Can you share the code snippets?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) I should put it under res/raw